# Function template specialization to force enum value with type

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, partial-specialization

A function is required to send messages, given a message type and a data structure of a type specific to the message type:

```
enum class MsgType
{
    msgInt,
    msgDouble,
    msgString
};

template < some template here >
void sendMessage(MsgType type, T value);
```

I expect to call this function in the following way:

```
sendMessage( MsgType::msgInt, 42 );
sendMessage( MsgType::msgString, "Answer to the life, etc,etc.");
//sendMessage( MsgType::msgDouble, "Should not compile");
//sendMessage<MsgType::msgString>( "That is easy!" );
```

How could I implement the previously described template function specialization?

Note: If possible, with C++11, but C++14 is also acceptable.

EDITED:

The current implementation, which only accept the MsgType as template parameter (not as function parameter).

```
template<MsgType Id, typename T>
void sendMessage(T data);

template<>void sendMesssage<MsgType::msgNumCar, int>( int data ){ //...   }
template<>void sendMesssage<MsgType::msgInt, int>( int data ){ //...   }
template<>void sendMesssage<MsgType::msgString, string>( string data ){ //...   }
// A call
sendMessage<MsgType::msgNumCar>( 42 );
```

Comment: `MsgType` seems unnecessary. Template specialization is done on template parameters, which you can leave for compiler to deduce. Roughly, what should `sendMessage` do?

Comment: If there is a sendMessage, on the other side, a receiveMessage is required, which need to match type. To trust programmers is good 99% of times, but this last 1% make you crazy debugging for 1 full day.

Comment: Is `recieveMessage` in the same process?

Comment: Yes, the full library is shared. But I expect more a "generic" solution than a trick for this specific case. (My purpose is to learn here)

Comment: Have you thought about three overloads of `sendMessage` and `receiveMessage`? Why do you think that would not work for your need?

Comment: How do you match the overloaded function with the MsgType?

Comment: You can do all sorts of stuff using templates and type traits. I am wondering whether you are trying to find the best solution for your problem or are you trying to force the use of templates because it sounds cool.

Comment: Any solution will have at least a +1. If it match the calls suggested in the question and avoid wrong types, it will probably win the "accepted as solution" status. I have curiosity for the template, but it is not a full must.

Answer (score 4):

Templates can have constant parameters which are known in compile-time. You could do the following:

```
enum MsgType {
    msgInt,
    msgDouble,
    msgString
};

template<int>
struct Message { };

template<>
struct Message<MsgType::msgInt> {
    static void send(int value) { cout << "int: " << value; }
};

template<>
struct Message<MsgType::msgDouble> {
    static void send(double value) { cout << "double: " << value; }
};

template<>
struct Message<MsgType::msgString> {
    static void send(const char* value) { cout << "string: " << value; }
};
```

And invoke it:

```
Message<MsgType::msgInt>::send(5);
Message<MsgType::msgDouble>::send(3.14);
Message<MsgType::msgString>::send("hello");

// will not compile
//Message<MsgType::msgDouble>::send("should not compile");
```

notice that the template parameter must be a constant (i.e. known at compile time). Which means that the following code won't compile:

```
int type = MsgType::msgInt;
Message<type>::send(123);
```

But, why won't you just create 3 overloads for `sendMessage`?

Comment: +1 @AdrianMaire Preserving the exact method call you presented cannot give compilation error on the wrong enum type, as the enum type sent is known only at runtime (as a method argument). You can still turn @IdanYadgar solution into a global method call with: `template<MsgType type, class T>
void sendMessage(T val) {
    Message<type>::send(val);
}`

And then invoke it:

`sendMessage<MsgType::msgInt> ( 42 );`
`sendMessage<MsgType::msgString> ("Answer to the life, etc,etc.");`
`// sendMessage<MsgType::msgDouble> ("Should not compile");`

Comment: There is not a way to force MsgType to be constexpr and detect the template parameter from it?

Comment: @AdrianMaire constexpr is not allowed on function parameters, so there is no way that I can think of to treat it as constexpr. (If there is a tricky way that would be interesting).

Comment: Enums in c++ are just integers, therefore the compiler can't prevent you from sending a specific integer to a method which accepts to receive an integer. The only way is a template specialization which decides what to do depends on the template parameter provided, because template parameters are known in compile time.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of validating that the user passes the correct message type enum value into the send function, prevent it entirely with some traits:

```
#include <iostream>

enum class MsgType
{
    msgInt,
    msgDouble,
    msgString
};

template <typename T>
struct MsgTypeOf;

template <>
struct MsgTypeOf<int>
{
    static MsgType msg_type;
};

template <>
struct MsgTypeOf<double>
{
    static MsgType msg_type;
};

template <>
struct MsgTypeOf<const char*>
{
    static MsgType msg_type;
};

MsgType MsgTypeOf<int>::msg_type = MsgType::msgInt;
MsgType MsgTypeOf<double>::msg_type = MsgType::msgDouble;
MsgType MsgTypeOf<const char*>::msg_type = MsgType::msgString;

template <typename T>
int sendMessage(T value)
{
    return static_cast<int>(MsgTypeOf<T>::msg_type);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << sendMessage(42) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sendMessage("Answer to the life, etc,etc.") << std::endl;
    std::cout << sendMessage(42.42) << std::endl;
}
```

Output:
0
2
1

Comment: Very interesting code!! Actually you do the reverse: instead of forcing a message type with a data type, you get the message type from the data type.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I am totally off base...

You can have three overloads of `sendMessage` and `receiveMessage`.

```
void sendMessage(int m);
void sendMessage(double m);
void sendMessage(std::string const& m);
```

and

```
void receiveMessage(int& m);
void receiveMessage(double& m);
void receiveMessage(std::string& m);
```

There is no need for an `enum` or a function template.

**Update, in response to OP's comment**

My suggestion:

1. Create `struct`s to be used as tags instead of an `enum`.
2. Overload `sendMessage` and `receiveMessage` using the tag `struct`s.

---

```
struct int_message_t {};
struct double_message_t {};
struct string_message_t {};
struct username_message_t {};
struct numcars_message_t {};
struct bigstruct_message_t {};
```

And then overload them using

```
void sendMessage(int_message_t, int m);
void sendMessage(double_message_t, double m);
void sendMessage(string_message_t, std::string const& m);
void sendMessage(username_message_t, std::string const& m);
void sendMessage(numcars_message_t, int m);
void sendMessage(bigstruct_message_t, big_struct const& m);
```

and

```
void receiveMessage(int_message_t, int& m);
void receiveMessage(double_message_t, double& m);
void receiveMessage(string_message_t, std::string& m);
void receiveMessage(username_message_t, std::string& m);
void receiveMessage(numcars_message_t, int& m);
void receiveMessage(bigstruct_message_t, big_struct& m);
```

If you can use a function template to make the implementations of these functions, that will be nice but I would still leave that as an implementation detail.

Comment: What if you have several MsgType values which require the same type?

Comment: @AdrianMaire, elaborate please.

Comment: Your solution is a simple overloaded function: It does not protect from sending a "MsgInt" with a string value. If you add more MsgType like "msgNumCars", "msgUserName", "msgBigStructure".... there is no match at all between this message and the data type provided.

Comment: +1 @AdrianMaire I believe this is the closest you can get to what you asked for. Maybe you can add a `static const int value` with a unique value per each `struct`, so it will actually be used similarly to `enum`.

Answer (score 1):

Preserving the exact method call you presented cannot give compilation error on the wrong enum type, as the enum type sent is known only at runtime (as a method argument). And you cannot overload on function parameter value (only on type).

Getting the enum as a template parameter ([@IdanYadgar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38082279/2085626)) allows check at compile time.

Overloading on type ([@MarkB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38082184/2085626) and [@RSahu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38082048/2085626) - using two different approaches) is also a nice option.

I believe [@RSahu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38082048/2085626) is the closest you can get to what you asked for. Maybe you can add a `static const int value` for each `struct` so it will actually be used as `enum`.